# Grid doesn´t show two images side by side in mobile phone

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-6

I am using Foundation 6.5.3 - the latest - codes.
But the images row wont work in a mobile.
I want two images side by side but only get one.

complete page here:

http://tnaaevent.se/golf_rattoslatt3.asp

Nr 1 - 2019

Comment: Could you kindly include your source code?

Comment: It is more easy to open the url and look at the code.

Comment: line 221 in http://tnaaevent.se/css_ej_foundation/golf6damkommitten.css is making the minimum width: 300px when I test on  360x 640 phone emulator.  If I comment that part out it fits 2 per row.

Comment: I have solved it!

Comment: Hi Tyddlywink. I saw that and got rid of it. That was the solution. Thanks for helping me anyway.